# iOS: Navigation bar item disappearing and reappearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationitem

Trying to add and remove navigation Bar Items on the navigation bar, some bar items disappear.

When I run the codes below at viewDidLoad, they work fine.

```
-(void) resetNavigationBarRearrangeMode {

    NSArray*rightBarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:actionCancel, actionSave, actionAddItem, actionRearrange, nil];

    self.navBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightBarItems;

}
```

When I try to remove some of the bar button items, it appears fine.

```
- (IBAction)cancelClicked:(id)sender {



    NSArray*rightBarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:actionRearrange, nil];


    self.navBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightBarItems;

    Log(@"running cancel");
}
```

But when I clicked rearrange to run the below code, this doesn't work.

```
- (IBAction)rearrangeClicked:(id)sender {


        [self resetNavigationBarRearrangeMode];


}
```

Anyone know what's wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: try set the rightBarButtonItems to nil before adding the new items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `barButtonItems` are overlapped each and every time you call the method. You need to reset the `barButtonItems` by setting it as `nil` before calling the method for rearranging.

```
 - (IBAction)rearrangeClicked:(id)sender {

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    [self resetNavigationBarRearrangeMode];


    }
```

It would work. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588767/how-do-i-hide-show-the-right-button-in-the-navigation-bar) for further assistance.

Comment: i tried self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;.. Do you mean to put self.navBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil; both ways doesn't work.