# hide and show left navigation bar button on demand in iOS-7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, storyboard, uinavigationitem

I added my left navigation bar button using the storyboard. but I want it to hide when I first load the screen. And then in response to something else, I want it to show. The navigation bar has a method for hiding the back button. But there is no method for hiding/showing the left button. Is there a simple way for doing this? Or do I have to use two methods: the hiding method creates an empty button and the showing method creates the correct button? The button in question is just the `Add` template that iOS provides (which makes it easy to just use the one in the storyboard than to create my own).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is how I solved it

```
-(void) hideAndDisableRightNavigationItem
{
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
}

-(void) showAndEnableRightNavigationItem
{
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: That is sexy. Best solution on stack.

Comment: I referenced this in my answer on a similar question. Hope you don't mind.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588767/how-do-i-hide-show-the-right-button-in-the-navigation-bar/27262875#27262875

Comment: What if I have more than one navigation bar button items? left or right where ever..

Answer (score 8):

Swift version of @learner answer

```
func hideAndDisableRightNavigationItem (){
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

func showAndEnableRightNavigationItem(){
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor. blackColor()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I did. On the initial screen I wanted to hide the navigation bar:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

On the second screen I wanted to show the navigation bar so I set:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```