# How to delete Navigation Bar Button Item

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am pushing ViewController programmatically using this code:

```
 LoginInfoVC *nextScr = (LoginInfoVC *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginInfoVC"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextScr animated:YES];
```

And in my LoginInfoVC didLoad Method I am using this code to remove back button
but its not working:

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

I also used this code:

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588767/how-do-i-hide-show-the-right-button-in-the-navigation-bar)  but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
```